# Downloading file causes user to be logged out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 website (due to hosting restrictions) whereby there's an admin restricted area with an action link that downloads a .csv or .xlsx file for the user when clicked.

Locally it works absolutely fine.

However, when pushed out to production, clicking the download button causes the user to be logged out and presented with the login screen as if they haven't been authenticated. Then, logging in causes the download to actually start (due to the returnUrl being set to the download button's action link).

The following code snippets are trimmed versions of what I've got:

**AdminController**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AdminController : BaseController
    {
         ...

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Users()
        {
            var users = _context.PreSignups
                                .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).ToList();

            CheckMessages();

            return View(users);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Download_PreSignupUsersToExcel()
        {
            var users = _context.PreSignups
                                .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).ToList().ToDataTable();

            DocumentService.WriteToSpreadsheet(users, $"PreSignupUsers_{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss")}.xlsx", true, Response);

            // NOTE: Due to the Response being sent back in DocumentService.WriteToSpreadsheet() the below is mostly redundant as the response has already closed by this point.

            TempData["Message"] = "Download started";

            return RedirectToAction("Logs", "Admin");
        }
```

**DocumentService.cs**

```
public static void WriteToSpreadsheet(DataTable dt, string filename, bool hasHeaders, HttpResponseBase response, enFileType fileType = enFileType.Xlsx)
        {

            ... // Build the data

            // Write the data
            using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
            {
                response.Clear();
                workbook.Write(exportData);
                if (fileType == enFileType.Xlsx) //xlsx file format
                {
                    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={filename}");
                    response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray());
                }
                else if (fileType == enFileType.Xls)  //xls file format
                {
                    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={filename}");
                    response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
                }
                response.End();
            }
        }
```

**The View**
Contains the following actionlink at some point to make a GET call to the above. Clicking this causes the user to be apparently logged out to the login screen with `"admin/Download_PreSignupUsersToExcel"` as the returnUrl.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export .Xlsx", "Download_PreSignupUsersToExcel", "Admin", null, new { @class="btn btn-primary" })
```

For reference, the BaseController inherits from the Controller class and provides a convenient way of storing the ApplicationDbContext and a LoggingService and shouldn't have any effect on the above.

I've gone code-blind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as it turns out a browser will only listen for a single response for a specific request.

I moved the download portion of code into its own AdminDownloadController API. Then by removing `response.End();` and returning the `HttpResponseMessage` with all of the relevant data and replacing the standard `ActionResult` from the controller with it, the download initiates in the same authenticated and authorised session, without logging the user out.

The caveat is that you can't do much with the response on the client-side, like display messages, without some JS magic. AJAX calls present problems with authentication and authorisation, so take the path of least resistance... unless you're into that sort of thing!

Here's a summary of the code that works for anyone that needs it:

**AdminDownloadController.cs**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AdminDownloadController : BaseApiController
    {

        // GET: api/AdminDownload/PreSignupUsersToExcel
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string downloadName)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            switch (downloadName)
            {
                case "PreSignupUsersToExcel":
                    var users1 = _context.PreSignups
                                .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).ToList().ToDataTable();

                    response = DocumentService.WriteToSpreadsheet(users1, $"PreSignupUsers_{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss")}.xlsx", true);
                    break;

                    ...

            }

            return response;
         }
     }
```

**DocumentService.cs**

```
public static HttpResponseMessage WriteToSpreadsheet(DataTable dt, string filename, bool hasHeaders, enFileType fileType = enFileType.Xlsx)
{            

    // Build Data
    ...

    // StreamData
    using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.Write(exportData);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(exportData.ToArray());
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;

        if (fileType == enFileType.Xlsx)
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        else if (fileType == enFileType.Xls)
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        return response;
    }
}
```

**WhateverView.cshtml**

```
...

@Html.ActionLink("Export .Xlsx", "AdminDownload", "Api", new { downloadName = "PreSignupUsersToExcel" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

...
```